# How to make a Multi-Select List of Values (Check Box) based on another Multi-Select List of Values (Check Box) in JasperReports Server?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a Multi-Select List of Values (Check Box) input control named *Animal Categories*, with the following values:
**Name            Value**
Birds              1
Mammals       2
Amphibians    3

and a Single Select Query input control named *Country*, with the following values:
Brazil
Australia
Portugal

The *Country's* SQL Query show values on when Amphibians is selected from the *Animal Categories*.

```
-- Some Oracle SQL Code
WHERE $X{IN, 3, animalcategory}
```

What I want now is to make *Country* input control a Multi-Select List of Values (Check Box) and keeping showing the values when the Amphibians is selected from the Animal Categories, but I don't know how to do that, since I have a List now and not a Query to be based on the Animal Categories' values.

Comment: I already have an Cascading Input working well, maybe I wasn't explainefull enough. But what I'm trying to do is a Cascanding Input with Multi-Select List of Values (Check Box), which doesn't have a Query field like Single Select List of values, to be based in my first Input Control.

Comment: I made another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61013694/how-to-make-a-multi-select-list-of-values-check-box-a-cascading-inpu-control-i